# AngularJS Calling C# Backend Method

Tags: c#, angularjs

I hope I don't come across as too stupid, because I'm sure this is so simple, but I can't figured it out. I need to understand how to make Angular call a specific method on a C# backend. I'm assuming that it would be an $http Get method call. But my question is, say I'm trying to load a Crystal report, would I put my C# code in a Controller? And if so when calling this method from angular would I just call the controller? Like url: '/Companies'? or would I reference the specific method? Like url: '/Companies/GetReport'?

Comment: ASP.Net WebApi is the standard for RESTful C# web servers at the moment... http://www.asp.net/web-api

Comment: also, I'm not really sure how this question is any different from your last question.... Angular and C# are not the same; they can communicate, but your questions seem to be how to make a service that any front end can communicate with, definitely not Angular specific.

Comment: Basically, you create an asp.net script that calls the method, and then use Angular to request the URL that runs the asp.net script.  The details depend upon which of the many frameworks (webforms, mvc, etc.) you choose to use.